# http live video streaming and embed ffplay?

Tags: html, ffmpeg

I have one query related to http live streaming concept.

In my cases:

case-1:  when I am playing the live streaming in ffplay, gives at most 2 seconds dealy.

case-2: while playing the live streaming in vlc player , gives at most 5 seconds delay.

case-3: In videojs player , shows at most 13 seconds delay.

Is there any solution to get case-1 in both 2 and 3 cases? And also May i know that can we embed ffplay into  html page ?

Comment: “Is there a way” yes. Write your own player. “Ffplay in a browser” not possible.